# A Dystopian Anti-Consumerist Novel

Tags: story-identification, novel, dystopia, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to remember a recently-published sci fi novel where all consumer decisions are made for you by predictive ai; for example, products you are predicted to want are automatically purchased and delivered to you. This is all run by a monolithic corporation called something like The Company. What book could this be?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.   Was this in English, or in German?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds a lot like [*Qualityland*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2250017) by Marc-Uwe Kling.  It's really *very* close, but the English translation only comes out today...

Quoting a review:

> Welcome to QualityLand, the best nation on Earth—because it was built for you. In QualityLand, everything is automated to make your life more convenient: digital personal assistants find everything from the best food to the best friends for you, a universal ranking system decides which social class you'll excel in and what career you should pursue, while advanced algorithms from the most successful company on Earth, TheShop, deliver necessities to your door without you needing to order them. Everything is easy, everything is personal, everything is quality.

From the [Amazon](https://www.amazon.ca/Qualityland-Marc-Uwe-Kling-ebook/dp/B07RLKZCV5/ref=sr_1_1?qid=1578372708&refinements=p_27%3AMarc-Uwe%20Kling&s=books&sr=1-1) blurb:

> Welcome to QualityLand, the best country on Earth. Here, a universal ranking system determines the social advantages and career opportunities of every member of society. An automated matchmaking service knows the best partners for everyone and helps with the break up when your ideal match (frequently) changes. And the foolproof algorithms of the biggest, most successful company in the world, TheShop, know what you want before you do and conveniently deliver to your doorstep before you even order it.